# SELECT Distinct based on few columns

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have an MS SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date_of_Record, Computer_Name, IP_Address, Agent_Version, Mac_Address
FROM [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers
WHERE Computer_Name in (SELECT Computer_Name
                        FROM [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers
                        GROUP BY Computer_Name
                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Agent_Version) > 1)
AND [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
AND [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
ORDER BY Computer_Name, Date_of_Record
```

That outputs

```
Date        Computer   IP               Version         Mac
2014-10-24  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.3001.165   NULL
2014-10-25  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.3001.165   NULL
2014-10-26  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.3001.165   NULL
2014-10-27  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.4013.4013  NULL
2014-10-28  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.4013.4013  NULL
2014-10-29  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.5773.2276  NULL
```

How to change the `SELECT DISTINCT` statement so it outputs records with distinct **Version** at the earliest **Date**, i.e

```
Date        Computer   IP               Version         Mac
2014-10-24  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.3001.165   NULL
2014-10-27  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.4013.4013  NULL
2014-10-29  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.5773.2276  NULL
```

@Pradeep

Your solution outputs

```
Date        Computer   IP               Version         Mac
2014-10-17  COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.3001.165   NULL
2014-10-17  COMP002    10.10.10.11      12.1.4013.4013  NULL
2014-10-17  COMP003    10.10.10.12      12.1.5773.2276  NULL
2014-10-17  COMP004    10.10.10.14      11.0.5003.2276  NULL
```

@1010 and @AWinkle

If I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT Computer_Name, IP_Address, Agent_Version
FROM dbo.Computers
WHERE Computer_Name in (SELECT Computer_Name
                        FROM dbo.Computers
                        GROUP BY Computer_Name
                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Agent_Version) > 1)
AND dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
ORDER BY Computer_Name
```

Then I get

```
Computer   IP               Version         Mac
COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.3001.165   NULL
COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.4013.4013  NULL
COMP001    10.10.10.10      12.1.5773.2276  NULL
```

How do I modify the SQL statement so it adds corresponding `Date_of_Record` column

Comment: What happens when you put the `DISTINCT` keyword next to Version instead of Date_of_Record?

Comment: @IronMan84 I get `Incorrect syntax ...`

Comment: @IronMan84 Not possible. `DISTINCT` applies to the entire row, not to any individual column(s).

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, my T-SQL is a little rusty :-)

Comment: Use MIN(Date) and do a group by on the other columns to aggregate and return the smallest date value for that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is by using window function.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT Row_number()
                           OVER (
                             partition BY Computer_Name,Agent_Version
                             ORDER BY Date_of_Record) RN,
                         Date_of_Record,
                         Computer_Name,
                         IP_Address,
                         Agent_Version,
                         Mac_Address
         FROM   [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers
         WHERE  Computer_Name IN (SELECT Computer_Name
                                  FROM   [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers
                                  GROUP  BY Computer_Name
                                  HAVING Count(DISTINCT Agent_Version) > 1)
                AND [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
                AND [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100')
SELECT Date_of_Record,
                     Computer_Name,
                     IP_Address,
                     Agent_Version,
                     Mac_Address
FROM   cte
WHERE  RN = 1
ORDER  BY Computer_Name,
          Date_of_Record
```

Comment: This query returns data I cannot comprehend. It returns four records with the same date.

Comment: @Glowie - four records for same Agent_Version??

Comment: There are different agent versions, but it does not show the records I am looking for. Will post output in OP

Comment: how do I remove column `RN`?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you cannot select distinct by only a select number of columns, you need to group them. Using the `MIN` function will provide distinct version (by computer/ip/mac) at the earliest date.

```
SELECT MIN(Date_of_Record) Earliest_Date_of_Record, Computer_Name, IP_Address, Agent_Version, Mac_Address
FROM [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers
WHERE Computer_Name in (SELECT Computer_Name
                    FROM [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers
                    GROUP BY Computer_Name
                    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Agent_Version) > 1)
AND [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
AND [SEP_Versions].dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
GROUP BY Computer_Name, IP_Address, Agent_Version, Mac_Address
ORDER BY Computer_Name, Date_of_Record
```

Comment: I get the error `Column SEP_Versions.dbo.Computers.Date_of_Record is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` When I add `Date_of_Record` to `GROUP BY` I get the same output as original. What other AGGREGATE functions are there?

Comment: @AWinkle Please see OP

Comment: Try 'ORDER BY Computer_Name, Earliest_Date_of_Record', I didn't update the date column name.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
SELECT MIN(Date_of_Record), Computer_Name, IP_Address, Agent_Version, Mac_Address
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Computer_Name, IP_Address, Agent_Version, Mac_Address
ORDER BY ...
```

the group by clause will aggregate rows for each combination of Computer_Name, IP_Address, Agent_Version, Mac_Address.
MIN(Date_of_Record) will calculate for each group the earliest date.

Comment: I get the error `Column SEP_Versions.dbo.Computers.Date_of_Record is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` When I add `Date_of_Record` to `GROUP BY` I get the same output as original. What other AGGREGATE functions are there?

Comment: @Glowie you should sort by MIN(Date_of_Record), Date_of_Record is not valid because for each group there will be only one row, and Date_of_Record can have multiple values.